# RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4 at new Float32Array

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use my own custom model to classify between dogs and cats in react native app. Three errors appears. Could you please help me to resolve these errors?
Here is the URL of an Image.

`url='https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg'`

```
backend.js:32 The shape of the input tensor ([null,50,50,32]) does not match the expectation of layer conv2d_1: [null,100,100,3]
n @ backend.js:32

backend.js:32 The shape of the input tensor ([null,25,25,64]) does not match the expectation of layer conv2d_2: [null,100,100,3]
n @ backend.js:32

backend.js:32 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4
RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)
```

Here is my code:

```
 async function getPrediction(url){
    // setDisplayText("Loading Tensor Flow")
    setDisplayText("Loading Flow")
    await tf.ready()
    setDisplayText("Loading My model")
    const modelJson = require('../assets/model/model.json');
    const modelWeights = require('../assets/model/group1-shard.bin');
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
    setDisplayText("Fetching image");
    const response =await fetch(url, {}, { isBinary : true});
    setDisplayText("Getting image buffer")
    const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer()
    setDisplayText("Getting Image tensor")
    const imageTensor = imageToTensor(url);
    setDisplayText("Loading Result")
    const prediction = (await model.predict(imageTensor))[0]; 
    setDisplayText("WOW")
}

function imageToTensor(rawImageData){
    //Function to convert jpeg image to tensors
    const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true;
    const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY);
    // Drop the alpha channel info for mobilenet
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3);
    let offset = 0; // offset into original data
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
      buffer[i] = data[offset];
      buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1];
      buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2];
      offset += 4;
    }
    return tf.tensor3d(buffer, [height, width, 3]);
  }
```

Comment: Try `const prediction = await model.predict(imageTensor)`.

Comment: Also please include the shape of `imageTensor` and `url`

Comment: @yudhiesh could you please be specific  where to include the shape  of imageTensor and URL?

Comment: In the question.

Comment: I just included it in the question. But the error is same no matter which image do I use.

Comment: You are passing in the url not an image to `imageToTensor`.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone encountering the same error:
If you used this python code to convert the model:

```
# python
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(decoder, path)
```

You need the entire folder when loading the model with

```
// JS
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel("model.json")
```

Don't leave the bin files out

Answer (score -1):

You are making a prediction on the `url` of the image and not the actual image. Applying the function `imageToTensor()` on the results of `await response.arrayBuffer()` should  work.

```
const response =await fetch(url, {}, { isBinary : true});
setDisplayText("Getting image buffer")
const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer()
setDisplayText("Getting Image tensor")
const imageTensor = imageToTensor(rawImageData);
setDisplayText("Loading Result")
const prediction = await model.predict(imageTensor); 
setDisplayText("WOW")
```

Comment: The error seems to be coming from before response. I tried commenting the code after loadLayersModel(). It didn't print the displayText.

Comment: Wrap the code in a try catch statement and add the error.

Comment: It threw this error:  ExceptionsManager.js:179 RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)
    at _loop_2 (io_utils.js:206)
    at Object.decodeWeights (io_utils.js:223)
    at decodeModelAndOptimizerWeights (models.js:321)
    at models.js:302
    at step (models.js:54)
    at Object.next (models.js:35)
    at fulfilled (models.js:26)
    at tryCallOne (core.js:37)
    at core.js:123

Comment: @RixantRokaha create a react native code-sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-q4qymyp2l6?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js:2936-2941). Looking back, what you said does not make sense. Before loading the model all you do is check whether Tensorflow.js is ready.